# How to better write this C++ program

Tags: c++, oop, c++11

I have many modules (C++ classes) that use a common class (HW_util)

HW_util class actually initializes the Hardware.

All the modules are initialized with the address of HW_util object. I have 30+ modules and so 30 odd lines that just do the initialization and I find this code ugly. **Is there a better way to do this?**

```
class HW_Util
{
    InitHW();
    Functionality1_onHW();
    Functionality2_onHW();
    ..
    CleanupHW();
};


class Module1
{
    Module1(HW_Util *util) { m_Util = util; }
    ..
    HW_Util *m_Util;    

    void DoSomething()
    {
        //uses m_Util to do something
    }
};

class Module2
{
    Module2(HW_Util *util) { m_Util = util; }
    ..
    HW_Util *m_Util;    

    void DoSomething()
    {
        //uses m_Util to do something
    }
};

...
//I have around 30 such modules..
...



void main()
{
    HW_Util util;

    Module1 mod1(&util);    //I am passing util to all these modules, and I have around 30 such modules, ugly code
    Module1 mod1(&util);
    Module3 mod1(&util);
    Module4 mod1(&util);
    Module5 mod1(&util);


    util.InitHW();  //actually fill up the util

    mod1.DoSomething();
    mod2.DoSomething();
    ..


    util.CleanupHW();
}
```

Comment: If you want to improve working code, you better ask at [SE Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: you code use inheritance, templates and another c++'s facilities

Comment: My question was moved to SE and then back here. I don't know how this question is not legitimate. I can not add the real code here, plus it would be too long.

Comment: @viktorzeid I tried to give you an idea, even if it's actually hard to say without the real code. Hoping it can help you.

Comment: Thanks @skypjack, I will checkout the mixins, didn't know about them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a class like this one:

```
template<typename... M>
struct Modules: M... {
    Modules(HW_Util *util): M...{util} {}
};
```

Then, within your `main`, specialize it and initialize it as it follows:

```
Modules<Module1, Module2> modules{&util};
```

Note that `Modules<Module1, Module2>` **is** both `Module1` and `Module2`.
Thus, the following applies:

```
Module1 &m1 = modules;
Module2 &m2 = modules;
```

This means also that you can pass a reference to `Modules<Module1, Module2>` whenever a reference either to `Module1` or `Module2` is required, as an example at a function call.

Look for *mixins* on the web for further details about this idiom.